# в QInputDialog выводит запятую вместо точки для getDouble

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите пожалуйста - использую для ввода десятичного числа, почему-то по умолчанию выводит вместо точки запятую, хотя в обучалках показывает точку. Можете подсказать в чем дело или может в новых версиях только запятая используется? Точку ставить отказывается с клавиатуры.

```
double test = QInputDialog::getDouble(this, "Ошибка ввода!", "Недопустимая вероятность провала. Введите число от 0 до 1!", 0.0, -2147483647, 2147483647, 3, &ok );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator = '.';
```